# Theorem on alpha conversion in type free lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am going through Lemma 1.2.11 of "Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism" by Morten Heine Sørensen and Pawel Urzyczyn. There is a free sample that includes this lemma here: https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=_mtnm-9KtbEC

> 1.2.11 Lemma. If $M =_{\alpha} M'$ and $N =_{\alpha} N'$ then $M [ x := N ] =_{\alpha} M' [ x := N' ]$, provided that both sides are defined.
>
> PROOF. By induction on the definition of $M =_{\alpha} M'$. If $M = M'$ then proceed by induction on $M$. The only other interesting case is when we have $M = \lambda z P$ and $M' = \lambda y . P [ z := y ]$, where $y \notin FV ( P )$, and $P [ z := y ]$ is defined. If $x = z$, then $x \notin FV ( M ) = FV ( M' )$ by Lemma 1.2.10. Hence $M [ x := N ] = M =_{\alpha} M' = M' [ x := N' ]$ by Lemma 1.2.5. The case $x = y$ is similar. So assume $x \notin \{ y, z \}$. Since $M [ x := N ]$ is defined, $x \notin FV ( P )$ or $z \notin FV ( N )$. In the former case $M [ x := N ] = \lambda z P$ and $x \notin FV ( P [ z := y ] )$, so $M' [ x := N' ] = \lambda y . P [ z := y ] =_{\alpha} \lambda z . P$.
>
> It remains to consider the case when $x \in FV ( P )$ and $z \notin FV ( N )$. Since $M' [ x := N' ] = ( \lambda y . P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N' ]$ is defined, we have $y \notin FV ( N' )$, and thus also $y \notin FV ( P [ x := N' ] )$. By Lemma 1.2.6 it then follows that $M' [ x := N' ] = \lambda y . P [ z := y ] [ x := N' ] = \lambda y . P [ x := N' ] [ z := y ] =_{\alpha} [ z . P [ x := N' ]$. By the induction hypothesis $\lambda z . P [ x := N' ] =_{\alpha} \lambda z . P [ x := N ] = M [ x := N ]$.

I believe that $[ z . P [ x := N' ]$ is a misprint of $\lambda z . P [ x := N' ]$.

Referenced lemmas:

> 1.2.5. Lemma.
>
> (i) If $x \notin FV ( M )$ then $M [ x := N ]$ is defined, and $M [ x := N ] = M$.
>
> (ii) If $M [ x := N ]$ is defined then $y \in FV ( M [ x := N ] )$ if and only if either $y \in FV ( M )$ and $x \neq y$ or both $y \in FV ( N )$ and $x \in FV ( M )$.
>
> (iii) The substitution $M [ x := x ]$ is defined and $M [ x := x ] = M$.
>
> (iv) If $M [ x := y ]$ is defined, then $M [ x := y ]$ is of the same length as $M$.
>
> 1.2.6 Lemma. Assume that $M [ x := N ]$ is defined, and both $N [ y := L ]$ and $M [ x := N ] [ y := L ]$ are defined, where $x \neq y$. If $x \notin FV ( L )$ or $y \notin FV ( M )$ then $M [ y := L ]$ is defined, $M [ y := L ] [ x := N [ y := L ] ]$ is defined, and $M [ x := N ] [ y := L ] = M [ y := L ] [ x := N [ y := L ] ]$.
>
> 1.2.10 Lemma. If $M =_{\alpha} N$ then $FV ( M ) = FV ( N )$.

Substitution is defined as in this question:
[Formal definition of substitution being defined in type free lambda calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109334/formal-definition-of-substitution-being-defined-in-type-free-lambda-calculus)

Alpha conversion is defined as:

> The relation $=_{\alpha}$ ($\alpha$-conversion) is the least (i.e. smallest) transitive and reflexive relation on $\Lambda^{-}$ satisfying the following.
>
> - If $y \notin FV ( M )$ and $M [ x := y ]$ is defined then $\lambda x M =_{\alpha} \lambda y . M [ x := y ]$.
> - If $M =_{\alpha} N$ then $\lambda x M =_{\alpha} \lambda x N$, for all variables $x$.
> - If $M =_{\alpha} N$ then $MZ =_{\alpha} NZ$.
> - If $M =_{\alpha} N$ then $ZM =_{\alpha} ZN$.

I think that the case in question can be stated as:

H1. Let $P \in \Lambda^{-}$.

H2. Let $y$ be any variable.

H3. Let $z$ be any variable.

H4. Let $y \notin FV ( P )$.

H5. Let $P [ z := y ]$ be defined.

H6. Let $x$ be any variable.

H7. Let $N \in \Lambda^{-}$.

H8. Let $N' \in \Lambda^{-}$.

H9. Let $N =_{\alpha} N'$.

H10. Let $( \lambda z . P ) [ x := N ]$ be defined.

H11. Let $( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N' ]$ be defined.

Prove: $( \lambda z . P ) [ x := N ] =_{\alpha} ( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N']$.

If this is the case then I have:

T1. $( \lambda z . P ) =_{\alpha} ( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] )$ by H1 - H5 and the definition of $\alpha$-conversion.

T2. $FV ( ( \lambda z . P ) ) = FV ( ( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] ) )$ by T1 and Lemma 1.2.10.

T3. $FV ( N ) = FV ( N' )$ by H9 and Lemma 1.2.10.

A1. Let $x = z$.

A1-T1. $z \notin FV ( P ) - \{ z \}$.

A1-T2. $FV ( P ) - \{ z \} = FV ( ( \lambda z . P ) )$.

A1-T3. $x \notin FV ( ( \lambda z . P ) )$ by A1, A1-T1, and A1-T2.

A1-T4. $x \notin FV ( ( \lambda y . P [ z := y ] ) )$ by A1-T3 and T2.

A1-T5. $( \lambda z . P ) [ x := N ] = ( \lambda z . P )$ by A1-T3 and Lemma 1.2.5 (i).

A1-T6. $( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N' ] = ( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] )$ by A1-T4 and Lemma 1.2.5 (i).

A1-T7. $( \lambda z . P ) [ x := N ] =_{\alpha} ( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N' ]$ by T1, A1-T5, and A1-T6.

A2. Let $x = y$.

A2-T1. $y \notin FV ( P [ z := y ] ) - \{ y \}$.

A2-T2. $FV ( P [ z := y ] ) - \{ y \} = FV ( ( \lambda y . P [ z := y ] ) )$.

A2-T3. $x \notin FV ( ( \lambda y . P [ z := y ] ) )$ by A2, A2-T1, and A2-T2.

A2-T4. $x \notin FV ( ( \lambda z . P ) )$ by A2-T3 and T2.

A2-T5. $( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N' ] = ( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] )$ by A2-T3 and Lemma 1.2.5 (i).

A2-T6. $( \lambda z . P ) [ x := N ] = ( \lambda z . P )$ by A2-T4 and Lemma 1.2.5 (i).

A2-T7. $( \lambda z . P ) [ x := N ] =_{\alpha} ( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N' ]$ by T1, A2-T5, and A2-T6.

A3. Let $x \neq y$ and $x \neq z$.

A3-T1. $x \neq y$ by A3.

A3-T2. $x \neq z$ by A3.

A3-T3. $P [ x := N ]$ is defined by H10, A3-T2, and (e) of the definition of substitution.

A3-T4. $( \lambda z . P ) [ x := N ] = ( \lambda z . P [ x := N ] )$ by H10, A3-T2, and (e) of the definition of substitution.

A3-T5. $x \notin FV ( P )$ or $z \notin FV ( N )$ by H10, A3-T2, and (e) of the definition of substitution.

A3-T6. $P [ z := y ] [ x := N' ]$ is defined by H11, A3-T1, and (e) of the definition of substitution.

A3-T7. $( \lambda y . P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N' ] = ( \lambda y . P [ z := y ] [ x := N' ] )$ by H11, A3-T1, and (e) of the definition of substitution.

A3-T8. $x \notin FV ( P [ z := y ] )$ or $y \notin FV ( N' )$ by H11, A3-T1, and (e) of the definition of substitution.

A3-A4. Let $x \notin FV ( P )$.

A3-A4-T1. $P [ x := N ] = P$ by A3-A4 and Lemma 1.2.5 (i).

A3-A4-T2. $( \lambda z . P [ x := N ] ) = ( \lambda z . P )$ by A3-A4-T1.

A3-A4-T3. $x \notin FV ( y )$ by A3-T1.

A3-A4-T4. $x \notin FV ( P [ z := y ] )$ by H5, A3-A4, A3-A4-T3, and Lemma 1.2.5 (ii).

A3-A4-T5. $P [ z := y ] [ x := N' ] = P [ z := y ]$ by A3-A4-T4 and Lemma 1.2.5 (i).

A3-A4-T6. $( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] [ x := N' ] ) = ( \lambda y . P [ z := y ] )$ by A3-A4-T5.

A3-A4-T7. $( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N' ] = ( \lambda y . P [ z := y ] )$ by A3-T7 and A3-A4-T6.

A3-A4-T8. $( \lambda z . P ) [ x := N ] =_{\alpha} ( \lambda y. P [ z := y ] ) [ x := N' ]$ by A3-T4, A3-A4-T2, T1, and A3-A4-T7.

A3-A5. Let $x \in FV ( P )$.

A3-A5-T1. $z \notin FV ( N )$ by A3-A5 and A3-T5.

A3-A5-T2. $x \in FV ( P [ z := y ] )$ by H5, A3-A5, A3-T2, and Lemma 1.2.5 (ii).

A3-A5-T2. $y \notin FV ( N' )$ by A3-T8 and A3-A5-T2.

I do not understand the remaining part of the proof. It consists of:

> and thus also $y \notin FV ( P [ x := N' ] )$. By Lemma 1.2.6 it then follows that $M' [ x := N' ] = \lambda y . P [ z := y ] [ x := N' ] = \lambda y . P [ x := N' ] [ z := y ] =_{\alpha} [ z . P [ x := N' ]$. By the induction hypothesis $\lambda z . P [ x := N' ] =_{\alpha} \lambda z . P [ x := N ] = M [ x := N ]$.

Is there a further induction on $P$ at this point?

Comment: Could you add the statement of the lemma? Otherwise it is impossible to understand your question.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Added.

Comment: The case you refer to is the one where $M = \lambda z.P$, isn't it?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Yes.

Comment: It seems to me that you are putting together several questions (there are three different occurrences of "not certain why", referring to different problems). Please, could you be more precise? What is exactly unclear?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Updated. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Updated to clarify the third question.

Comment: What is the definition of substitution in this book?

Comment: How does the proof start, where the induction is set up and the cases are defined?

Comment: I can't read the free sample because of some google cookie thing, but the book is available at https://disi.unitn.it/~bernardi/RSISE11/Papers/curry-howard.pdf . But I can't find this lemma 1.2.11; maybe it's another edition with different definitions/theorems?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Updated. I think I am most confused at the moment by how the induction is being done.

Comment: I was not expecting there to be an induction hypothesis for the case at the end of the proof.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Yes, the text you link to seems to be a different edition. I have added the full proof as stated in the text to the question.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Updated again. I hope this is clearer.